# Does Professor Goodfeels disappear sometimes?

Tags: fallout-4

I seem to have lost Professor Goodfeels from the co-op, but I don't *think* he got killed during a raid (and I haven't found any robo-corpse). I didn't send him off for maintenance using the terminal either.

Is it possible he just went walkies, and might come back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is know to have the issue of disappearing for no reason when you leave the area fast traveling away and back causes it the most, pc users can re-enable him with console commands as he is usually still in the game he just de-spawned. Best way to keep him there is to just keep his settings at just be or deactivate him though he will sometimes still disappear. Its a bug that will probably be fixed with future patches.

Comment: Thanks. PS4 here, so no console commands. I changed his protocols because I find "exterminate!" in his hippy voice hilarious, but if he re-spawns I'll put him back to "Just Be"